# UITextView in UITableViewCell subclass, how to keep the data separate from the view

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller

So I don't know what the best way to follow MVC is.  Similar to the address books app, I want to have a UITableVeiewcell that has the ability to edit notes.  I figured I would do that with a UITextView in a UITableViewCell subclass.  My subclass has just that as a property, and a label that says "notes".  I can see a few use cases that I need to consider,

1) when they are done editing and click outside or hit return.
2) when the text goes beyond the size of the cell I need to resize the cell.

Because my UITextView is in IB, is there a good way to define the delegate methods for the UITextView since my UITableView is in another ViewController subclass?  Like how do I pass that information back?

Or, is it better to create my UITableViewCell subclass in code since it's just a couple of items so all my delegate and resizing code is done in the view controller class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After text field editing was finished, you can store it's value in some dictionary in your controller. You can use cell's indexPath as key in this dictionary. In such way you will not lose your data with dequeue cells.

To resize cell you must call reloadData method and change rowHeight property of entire tableView or implement tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method to set needed row height to current cell.

I haven't use UIKit since iOS 3.1, so the second part of my answer can be out of date, but I hope it will help you =)